# I need help with a proof of topology properties (equality between sets)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with an exercise of topology (the Euclidean topology).  This is about the closure of a sets:

If $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\Omega_i$ with $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $i\in\{1,2,...,m\}$ holds $\Omega_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, then, $\overline{A}=\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}$

The problem is equivalent to proof the next equality $$\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\Omega_i}=\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}$$

I have one contention ($\subseteq$). We know that for all $i\in\{1,2,...,m\}$, $\Omega_j\subseteq\overline{\Omega_j}$, then, $\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\Omega_i\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}$. If we take closures of both sides, then $\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\Omega_i}\subseteq\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}}$.

But $\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}$ is a closed set. Then $\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}=\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}}$

Thus, $\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\Omega_i}\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_i^{m}\overline{\Omega_i}$.

I need help with the another way, i.e., proof the another contention ($\supseteq$)

Comment: For every $i$, $\Omega_i\subseteq A$ hence $\bar\Omega_i\subseteq\bar A$. Thus, $\bigcup\limits_i\bar\Omega_i\subseteq\bar A$, qed.

Comment: @Did, thanks. The proof is so clearly and small.